# Eclipse, project unable to launch

Tags: eclipse

i am using Eclipse Luna. My work space was C:\Users\user\workspace, that is my windows drive and it was not my default workspace, every time asked and i select it. Now  i changed my workspace into a folder in F drive. after writing a program in time of Running it is showing that....(the image given below.)
[image: Screen shoot of the error message.]

This fragment of code was tried to compile..

```
   public class Conditional_Operator 
    {
     static void main(String args[])
     {
      int studentGrade=0;
      System.out.printf(  studentGrade>=60 ? "\nPassed" : "\nFailed");
     }
    }`
```

How i can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the method main method name to `public static void main(String args[])`